# SQL preferred way for keyword search

Tags: sql, select, self-join

I have a table in the following format:

```
row_key  extID  tag   val
-------  -----  ---   ---
1         1     A     a
2         1     A     b
3         1     B     c
4         2     A     d
5         2     C     e
```

Now I want to have all extID's where there are several pairs of (tag, val) with specific values, for example:

```
(tag, val) = (A,a) AND (tag, val) = (B,c)
```

or,

```
(tag, val) = (C,e)
```

The number of constrains can change.

I can think of several ways to do this:

1. Perform a self-join for each constraint
2. Do the searching (iteratively) in the caller program (multiple SQL queries)
3. (Maybe?) write a SQL function to do this
4. Nested SELECT clauses (passing to the outer level the "extID" and using `WHERE extID IN (SELECT extID FROM ...)`
5. *The only true solution that I just can't find.*

Which one would be the preferred (fastest and most elegant) way to do this? (Except, of course, "Surely, 5. is the correct answer.")

I think a multiple SELF-join is quite elegant. However, I do not know if it is fast and comparatively memory-efficient.

Further, I would like to use a way that works with MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite without adaptation - That's why I can't use PIVOT afaiu.

Comment: What's the problem with your sample `(tag, val) = (A,a) AND (tag, val) = (B,c)`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it will return no result because each row, there will only be one value of `tag`.

Comment: @JW.: Well, obviously you need to fix the AND. I meant the tuple syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  extID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (tag = 'A' AND val = 'a') OR
        (tag = 'B' AND val = 'c')
GROUP   BY extID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e5e/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

**UPDATE 1**

since you haven't mentioned that there can be duplicate combination of `tag` and `val`, `DISTINCT` keyword is needed.

```
SELECT  extID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (tag = 'A' AND val = 'a') OR
        (tag = 'B' AND val = 'c')
GROUP   BY extID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag, val) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58e5e/6)

Comment: @Dukeling it's for another condition.

Comment: @JW @Dukeling I understand it differently. I think he's looking for `extID` values for which there are both the combinations `(A,a)` *and* `(B,c)`

Comment: @JW I thought about this one, too. The problem is when there are two identical rows (except for row_id, of course), this would fail, because the count would give the wrong result...

Comment: @w0lf and that's my answer is all about. *BOTH Combination*

Comment: @JW @Dukeling No, it returns the `extID` values for which there is either an `A,a` *or* a `B,c`

Comment: @w0lf are you sure with that? maybe you can click the `SQLFiddle` link.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth just playing devil's advocate here: see [this example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/135b9/1). Dukeling's comment above should solve this case

Comment: @JW.: Your query doesn't ensure that there is at least one row per constraint tuple. It will return an extId even if there was no row for `(B,c)` as long as there are two rows with `(A,a)`. In that regard, w0lf is correct. The question is: Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth that's why i updated the answer. I was assuming that there is a unique key enforce on `val` for every `tag`.

Comment: +1 it works OK now. It's probably worth mentioning that the value `2` in the `having` clause is in fact the number of criteria in the constraint (the number of tag/val pairs that must be present)

Comment: Thanks! the COUNT(DISTINCT tag,val) is the key (same in the version below)

Comment: There is a minor problem: Sqlite does not understand  COUNT(DISTINCT tag, val) - so I use COUNT(DISTINCT val). Postgresql however has no problem with it.

Comment: @user2055010 sqlite supports minimum feature. try this query if it works on sqlite http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/135b9/4

Answer (score 0):

The tuple syntax would work:

```
SELECT  extID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (tag, val) in (('A', 'a'), ('B', 'c'))
GROUP   BY extID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT tag, val) = 2
```

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag, val) = 2` ensures that each constraint tuple was present at least once. This means that the `2` needs to be adjusted to the number of constraint tuples in the query.

This would even work if you have two identical rows like this and the condition is `('C', 'e')`:

```
row_key  extID  tag   val
-------  -----  ---   ---
5         2     C     e
6         2     C     e
```

The query for this would look like this:

```
SELECT  extID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   (tag, val) in (('C', 'e'))
GROUP   BY extID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT tag, val) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I thinks its pretty similar to the answer from JW - the key is IMHO the COUNT(DISTINCT tag,val).

Comment: @user2055010: Indeed. I posted my answer because I find the tuple syntax much neater and found the answer by JW a little bit lacking in terms of explanations.